# How to define view in Ext.grid.panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I want to modify view of the grid and i started from base (i.e before i define my own view). But some how i am not even able to assign object to view property.
Please, anybody have any idea how to create view?? I tried following.

Example would be great.

```
var viewConfig = {emptyText: "My msg",stripeRows: false};

this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            id: "t-"+this.gridName+"-grid",
            header: true,
            title: gridTitle,
            border: false,
            store: store,            
            columns: cm,
            selModel: sm,
            loadMask: true,
            //viewConfig: viewConfig, // works fine
            //view: new Ext.view.Table() ,//Ext.grid.View(),//Ext.grid.View(viewConfig ),
            provider: this.page.provider
        });
```

If i de-comment "view: new Ext.view.Table()" line then it raise error and stops everything.
I keep commented and after grid creation, i can access view with this.grid.getView() property. But how to create own view object (where i can assign custom Templates)???

Many thanks.

Comment: Whats your problem? To customize the view use viewConfig as you still mention.

Comment: ViewConfig works fine, but i want define my own view. But if i decomment view: new Ext.view.Table() it raise error that me.selModel is undefined. How to create object of Ext.view.Table() and assign to "view" property?? this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            id: "t-"+this.gridName+"-grid",
            header: true,
            title: gridTitle,
            border: false,
            store: store,            
            columns: cm,
            selModel: sm,
            loadMask: true,
            view: new Ext.view.Table(),
            provider: this.page.provider
        });

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> This is the base class for both Ext.grid.View and Ext.tree.View and is
>   not to be used directly.

If you do want to create one yourself you need to configure the following **required** options.

```
itemSelector : String
store : Ext.data.Store
tpl : String/String[]
```

Look [into the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View) how to create your custom view.
*Good luck! If you need any help feel free to ask ;)*

```
Ext.define('Image', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name:'src', type:'string' },
        { name:'caption', type:'string' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    id:'imagesStore',
    model: 'Image',
    data: [
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-drawing.png', caption:'Drawing & Charts' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-data.png', caption:'Advanced Data' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png', caption:'Overhauled Theme' },
        { src:'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-perf.png', caption:'Performance Tuned' }
    ]
});

var imageTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="thumb-wrap">',
          '<img src="{src}" />',
          '<br/><span>{caption}</span>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
);

var theView = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
    tpl: imageTpl,
    itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
    emptyText: 'No images available'
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: "t-"+this.gridName+"-grid",
    header: true,
    title: gridTitle,
    border: false,
    store: store,            
    columns: cm,
    selModel: sm,
    loadMask: true,
    view: theView,
    provider: this.page.provider,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
//not tested but should work
```

Comment: first of all i tried with Ext.grid.View() and also put store:store,itemSelector:'tr.grid-row',tpl:'<div>{title}</div>' but that even does not work. (store is a variable assign object ofext.data.Jsonstore()), i tried tpl: new Ext.Template("<div>Hello {0}.</div>"); But nothing works. Do you know any link on internet to refer??

Comment: and also put store:store,itemSelector:'tr.grid-row',tpl:'<div>{title}</div>' but that even does not work. where store is a variable assign object of ext.data.Jsonstore()) and i tried tpl: new Ext.Template("<div>Hello {0}.</div>"); But nothing works. Do you know any link on internet to refer??

Comment: Hi there,Many thanks to provide example and link,
I tried following example but that does not work.

That raise following error on extjs 4 api "Live Preview"
TypeError: Cannot set property 'view' of undefined Please refer to this link http://jsfiddle.net/3hAsM/2/ as i am not able to post.